# What do units and layers do in neural network?

Tags: keras, deep-learning

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    # the hidden ReLU layers
    layers.Dense(units=4, activation='relu', input_shape=[2]),
    layers.Dense(units=3, activation='relu'),
    # the linear output layer 
    layers.Dense(units=1),
])
```

The above is a Keras sequential model example from Kaggle. I'm having a problem understanding these two things.

1. Are the units the number of nodes in a hidden layer? I see some people put 250 or what ever. What does the number do when it gets changed higher or lower?
2. Why would another hidden layer need to be added? What does it actually do the data to add more and more layers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answers in brief

1. units is representing how many neurons in a particular layer.When you have higher number,model has higher parameters to update during learning.Same thing goes to layers as well.(more layers and more neurons take more time to train the model).selecting how many neurons is depend on the use case and dataset and model architecture.
2. When you have more hidden layers, you have more parameters to update.More parameters and layers  meaning model is able to understand complex relationships hidden in the data. For example when you have a image classification(multiple), you need more deep layers with neurons to understand the features in the image, which use to classify in final layer.

[play with tensorflow playground,it will give great idea when you change the layers and neurons.](https://playground.tensorflow.org/#activation=tanh&batchSize=10&dataset=circle&regDataset=reg-plane&learningRate=0.03&regularizationRate=0&noise=0&networkShape=4,2&seed=0.16963&showTestData=false&discretize=false&percTrainData=50&x=true&y=true&xTimesY=false&xSquared=false&ySquared=false&cosX=false&sinX=false&cosY=false&sinY=false&collectStats=false&problem=classification&initZero=false&hideText=false)